# WooCommerce issue: Object of class WC_Product_Variation could not be converted to int

Tags: php, wordpress, object, woocommerce, instance

I built a plugin to access and modify some products fields with the Quick Edit of Woocommerce. In the shop I have `Simple` and `Variable` products. Each `Variable` product has two attribute: `Kg` and `Pièce`.

### What are the different fields ?

There are two fields that get the `regular price` of both variations of each `Variable` product.
I also need one `custom field` known as `_number_field` that simply is the same information as one of the variations. This custom field gets the regular price of one of the variation (which has the attribute "Kg").

### What do I need  ?

For the `custom field`, I need to access the `regular_price` of one of the two available variations of each `Variable` product.

In order to access the regular price of this variation, I create a new `WC_Product_Variation` class with the right (already created) variation ID.

I also need to get each variation's `regular_price`.

### The code to get the custom field

The following code (only part of the full code) is sent via the action `woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data`.

```php
// Getting both variations IDs of the product
$children = $product->get_children();

// I'm setting the default variation to the first variation ID
$default_variation_id = $children[0];

// I'm creating a first variation with the first variation ID in order to get it's attribute
$product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($default_variation_id);

// I can now compare it's attribute with the string "Kg".
// If it is true that means that the first variation ID has Kg has an attribute
// Otherwise I want the second variation, with has the string "Pièce" has an attribute
$product_variation->get_attribute("unite-de-commande") === "Kg" ? $default_variation_id = $children[0] : $default_variation_id = $children[1];

// Then I can get the right variation this way
$product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($default_variation_id);

// I can finally get the regular price of this product variation
$product_default_kg = $product_variation->get_regular_price();
```

### The issue I'm getting

The issue is that the values in the quick edit fields do not save, except for the first value which is the only one I access with the `new WC_Product_Variation` class.

In the logs, I can see the current error: `Object of class WC_Product_Variation could not be converted to int`.

The other two values are not accessed with this particular class.
Here's an excerpt of the code I use to save the other two fields.
This only includes one of the variations.

### The code to get one of the variation's regular price

```
$variations = $product->get_children();
$product_var_0_id = wc_get_product( $variations[0] );
$product_0 = wc_get_product( $product_var_0_id );
$product_0_def_attr = $product_0->get_attribute( 'unite-de-commande' );

if ( isset( $_REQUEST['_prix_variable_'. $product_0_def_attr] ) && $product_0_def_attr === "Kg") {
    $prix_variable_0 = $_REQUEST['_prix_variable_'. $product_0_def_attr];

    // Updating active price and regular price
    update_post_meta( $product_var_0_id, '_regular_price', $prix_variable_0 );
    update_post_meta( $product_var_0_id, '_price', $prix_variable_0 );
    wc_delete_product_transients( $product_var_0_id ); // Clear/refresh the variation cache
}
```

Could you help me understand why I'm getting this error ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your first code you can't get the right product variation ID from:

```
// I can now compare it's attribute with the string "Kg".
// If it is true that means that the first variation ID has Kg has an attribute
// Otherwise I want the second variation, with has the string "Pièce" has an attribute
$product_variation->get_attribute("unite-de-commande") === "Kg" ? $default_variation_id = $children[0] : $default_variation_id = $children[1];
```

as this doesn't give a variation id that you could use in:

```
// Then I can get the right variation this way $prod
$product_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($default_variation_id);
```

Instead use the following *(as you have only two variations for the parent variable product)*:

```
// Getting all variations IDs of the variable product
$children_ids = $product->get_children();

// Get first WC_Product_Variation instance Object
$variation = wc_get_product(reset($children_ids));

// Check if specific product attribute value is set on the first variation
if( $variation->get_attribute("unite-de-commande") !== "Kg" ) {
    // If not we get the 2nd WC_Product_Variation instance Object
    $variation = wc_get_product($children[1]);
}

// I can finally get the regular price of the right product variation
$regular_price = $variation->get_regular_price();
```

It should better work now.

---

On your 2nd code snippet there is a problem at this line:

```
$product_0 = wc_get_product( $product_var_0_id );
```

as `$product_var_0_id` is not an expected product **variation Id** but a `WC_Product_Variation()` object instance.

Also you can use `WC_Product` methods instead, and the correct code should be:

```
$children_ids        = $product->get_children();
$fist_variation      = wc_get_product( reset($children_ids) );
$fist_attr_udc_value = $fist_variation->get_attribute( 'unite-de-commande' );

if ( isset( $_REQUEST['_prix_variable_'. $fist_attr_udc_value] ) && $fist_attr_udc_value === "Kg") {
    $first_variable_price = esc_attr($_REQUEST['_prix_variable_'. $fist_attr_udc_value]);

    // Updating active price and regular price
    $fist_variation->set_regular_price( $first_variable_price );
    $fist_variation->set_price( $first_variable_price );
    $fist_variation->save() // Save data and Clear/refresh caches and transients
}
```

This 2nd code snippet should work.

Comment: Thank you, it works well for the first variation. But on the second code snippet, how can I access the second variation as reset() only get's me the first one ?

Comment: @JAGENINat Updated… now your first code should work too…